# Class C Addressing

Tags: ip, subnet

I recently saw someone use '200.1.2.0/18.' This doesn't make any sense to me. This is a Class C address with a subnet mask of /18. I thought the subnet mask for a Class C had to be at least /24. How exactly does this work?

Comment: Please tell your teacher (or better his boss) to read that article, including the part about how ***Classes should not be taught***. He/she is extremely lucky, if I were their boss they'd be out of a job for teaching about technologies that the world agreed to never speak of again 20 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

That address uses what's called Classless Inter-Domain Routing (or CIDR for short).  The class system has largely been abolished due to the rapidly diminishing IPv4 space.

Comment: abolished almost 20 years ago too!